# How to store a stack in a custom property in LiveCode?

Tags: ios, livecode

I'm working on an iOS app. I'd like to use a stack in the documents folder to store some data and preferences. I know I can include a stack in the engine folder by copying it when creating the standalone, but it seems easier and cleaner to store the stack in a custom property of my main stack. I could create the data stack on the first run of the app and store it in the documents folder.

I thought I could do this during development:

```
set the cDataStack of stack "My Main Stack" to URL ("binfile:" & tDataStackFilePath)
```

And then when it's time to create the new data storage stack do this:

```
set the defaultFolder to the documents folder
put the cDataStack of me into URL ("binfile:DataStack1.livecode")
```

... But this isn't working for me. It creates a 0kb file, when I would expect it to be a replica of the original.

Is this a reasonable way to create a data stack for iOS?
Does my code demonstrate the correct concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the cDataStack of me is empty. Perhaps, `me`is referring to the wrong control or stack. Try this:

```
// set the property
put URL ("binfile:" & tDataStackFilePath) into myStackData
if myStackData is not empty then
  set the cDataStack of stack "My Main Stack" to myStackData
  put the result into rslt
  if rslt is not empty then
    beep
    answer error rslt
  end if
else
  beep
  answer error "This file is empty or doesn't exist."
end if

// get the propety
put specialFolderpath("documents") & "/DataStack1.LiveCode" into myPath
if the cDataStack of me is not empty then
  put the cDataStack of me into URL ("binfile:" & myPath)
  put the result into rslt
  if rslt is not empty then
    beep
    answer error rslt
  end if
else
  beep
  answer error "The property is empty."
end if
```

You don't need to write a stack to disk before opening it. You can do this:

```
go stack the cDataStack of me
put the result into rslt
if rslt is not empty then
  beep
  aswer error rslt
end if
```

Comment: Confirmed... works a charm. Yes, "me" was referring to the test button containing the stack, and not the stack itself. Also, I think perhaps my file URL was not formed properly. Regardless, it's working now. Thanks!